Is it possible in .net core to access the graphics hardware screen refresh event?
I am looking to do some winforms drawing, and while I am aware there is no way of directly integrating the redraw with the hardware, I am wondering if there is at least an event that is accessible every time the screen refreshes at its 60/72/144 Hz.
I am trying to devise a timer with an equivalent rate, but any integer timings end up not being ever quite at the same frequency.

What's the overall goal here? If it's to reduce flicker, etc, you ought to read up on the built in functionality for double buffering. If it's something else, please share it. The likelihood that, in 2024, you need to be building logic directly based on a screen's refresh rate is practically zero.

I'd love to be good enough to be able to work in one of the modern graphics languages directly and essentially be able to perform 2D and 3D drawing operations directly. In lieu of that, I'm trying to just render animated geometry as smoothly as possible with as little processing overhead as possible.
